# 'invalid render array key' error when using an associated array for a twig variable

Tags: theming, 8

I have a list of images, and I want access to both the direct path to the image, and the path with an image style applied to it available to a Twig template.

I'm grabbing the images in my .theme file like so.

```
$images = $node->get('field_image');

foreach($images as $image){
    $image_style =Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('photos')->buildUrl($image->entity->getFileuri()),
    $image_path = file_create_url($image->entity->getFileuri()),    
}
```

I want to be able to access these attributes for each image by storing them in the `$variables` array.

I attempted to do so by using

```
foreach($images as $image){
    $image_style =Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('photos')->buildUrl($image->entity->getFileuri()),
    $image_path = file_create_url($image->entity->getFileuri()),    
    $variables['photos'][]['image_style'] = $image_style;
    $variables['photos'][]['image_path'] = $image_path;
}
```

However that didn't work and I received errors. After that I figured that maybe I needed to supply a more explicit associative array so I tried

```
    $variables['photos'] = array();
    $photo_paths = array();
    foreach($images as $image){
        $photo_paths += [
            $i => [
                'image_style' => Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('photos')->buildUrl($image->entity->getFileuri()),
                'image_path' => file_create_url($image->entity->getFileuri()),            
            ],
        ];

        $i += 1;
    }
    $variables['photos']= $photo_paths;
```

But then I receive the errors

> User error: "image_style" is an invalid render array key in
> Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

and

> User error: "image_path" is an invalid render array key in
> Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).

These errors continue for each image. I'm guessing that `$variables` can't handle nested associative arrays? Is there a way I can use an associative array inside a Twig variable? Or is there another way to accomplish the same task or storing the path and image style for each individual image to be displayed in a for loop in Twig?

Comment: No, Twig won't try to render an array, it wouldn't know what to do with it. Drupal augments Twig such that _any_ raw outputted array is treated as a render array, hence the error you're seeing when trying to render a non-render array. If you want to render the items in a non-render array, just use a traditional loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twig doesn't understand what you put in the keys `image_style` and `image_path`. Twig can handle only arrays when the children are renderable. And this means they have to contain a `'#type'` or `'#theme'` key with a valid render element or theme name. For image styles use the theme `image_style`:

```
$variables['photos'] = [];
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $variables['photos'][] = [
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#style_name' => 'photos',
    '#uri' => $image->entity->getFileUri(),
  ];
}
```

Then Twig can render the images like they're supposed to be rendered without the need for custom PHP code.

Comment: Ahh, so I need to supply it with actual render arrays?

Comment: Yes, in your case you reach two goals at once, you can render the whole thing with `{{ photos }}` and you don't need to use php code to generate the image styles.